# remove automatic created image border

Tags: html, css

[image: Normally, my image has no border, but when I open it in my website, it gets one, like this:]

*What should I do to remove it?*
I tried this (CSS):

```
img {
  width: 105%;
  margin: 0 -1rem;
}
```

but the image only became bigger than the screen.

---

## Edit

The image in html:

```
<section id="page_footer">
 <img class="stretch">
</section>
```

No CSS there, but the one to remove that border.

*Note: This is not a border like the css `border` statement. It's automatic created by firefox, I think, because the html inspector tells it's part of the image.*

Comment: You need to include the relevant html and any other css for your page.

Comment: Yes. It can be anything in the screenshot; margin, padding, border etc. I assume you're sure it's not part of the picture?

Comment: With only this screenshot to go by, it appears to be part of the image. The border is white, then switches to black further down the right side.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use a reset sheet

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually to erase native (or not) border, we do :

> border: 0

Comment: "Try this" answers are generally frowned upon. This would generally be better asked in a comment rather than an answer. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.